# Splitting a multidimensional array into two new arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [userId] => 35
    [fieldId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )

    [educationTitle] => Array
        (
            [0] => School1
            [1] => School2
            [2] => 3
            [4] => 
        )

    [educationDegree] => Array
        (
            [0] => Degree1
            [1] => Degree2
            [2] => 3
            [4] => 
        )

    [startDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-03-01
            [1] => 2013-03-03
            [2] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [endDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-03-02
            [1] => 2013-03-04
            [2] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [educationDescription] => Array
        (
            [0] => Description1
            [1] => Description2
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

And I have an array of ids called `matches`:

```
    [matches] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2

        )
```

I need to split the main array into two:

```
$eduAdd = array()
$eduUpdate = array()
```

`$eduAdd` will contain the non-matching **fieldId's** and `$eduUpdate` will contain the matching **fieldId's**.

`$eduAdd` Would look like this:

```
Array
    (
        [userId] => 35
        [fieldId] => Array
            (
                [2] => 3
                [4] => 4
            )

        [educationTitle] => Array
            (
                [2] => 3
                [4] => 
            )

        [educationDegree] => Array
            (

                [2] => 3
                [4] => 
            )

        [startDate] => Array
            (

                [2] => 1970-01-01
            )

        [endDate] => Array
            (

                [2] => 1970-01-01
            )

        [educationDescription] => Array
            (

                [2] => 
            )

    )
```

I tried this, but found out `in_array` does not work on multidimensional arrays:

```
foreach($filteredSubmittedData as $filteredUpdates){
    if(in_array($filteredUpdates['fieldId'], $matches)){
        echo "yup";
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Considering `$main` to be your main array and `$matches` to be your matches array:

```
$eduAdd = array();
$eduUpdate = array();
$itodel = array();
foreach ($main['fieldId'] as $i => $v)
    if (isset($matches[$i]) and $matches[$i] == $v)
        $itodel[] = $i;

foreach ($main as $key => $arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) continue;
    foreach ($arr as $i => $v) {
        if (in_array($i, $itodel))
            $eduUpdate[$key][$i] = $v;
        else
            $eduAdd[$key][$i] = $v;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

First of all we need to populate an array of indexes that are matched inside `$main['fieldId']`. Those are the indexes that will be moved to `$eduUpdate` and that will not be inserted into `$eduAdd`:

```
$itodel = array();
foreach ($main['fieldId'] as $i => $v)
    if (isset($matches[$i]) and $matches[$i] == $v)
        $itodel[] = $i;
```

Then we run another `foreach` loop that will actually split the `$main` array into the other two. The main condition is `if (in_array($i, $itodel))` because if we are watching an index that is inside the ones that should go into `$eduUpdate` then we should add it to it, otherwise we just insert it into `$eduAdd`.

Comment: Hey @Jueey! Thanks for the help. There is a typo here `($main['fieldId'] as $i = $v)` should be `=>` I changed it and ran it but got an error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` This is referring to `foreach ($arr as $i => $v) {`. It's getting really late here (2am) so I'll take another look at this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @relentless, yup, you were right for the typo. And I forgot that the first element in your main array is not an array therefore I've added `continue` to skip it. Fixed both. Now it whould work.

Answer (score 1):

`$filteredUpdates['fieldId']` itself is an array & as in_array needs a haystack it won't work as you expect. Try changing your if condition as,

```
if(array_intersect($filteredUpdates['fieldId'], $matches)){
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, but I'm getting `Warning: array_intersect() [function.array-intersect]: Argument #1 is not an array`

Comment: @relentless - But from above your given example array it is an array. Can you show as what exactly coming in `$filteredUpdates['fieldId']` ?

Comment: Correct. I even double checked it and what I posted above is correct.